# Difficulty loading an RTC driver - 22.04 with a DS3231, Raspberry Pi

Tags: drivers, raspberrypi, rtc

I have a DS3231 attached and can read / write time successfully.

i2cdetect shows it accessible on i2c address 0x68 as you'd expect.

None of the advice about configuring an i2c-rtc driver in /boot/config.txt has any effect.

dmesg |grep 3231 returns nothing.

dmesg |grep rtc likewise, except for a message:
 `Unknown kernel command line parameters "fixrtc splash", will be passed to user space`

I note /boot/config-5.15.0-1015-raspi (the most recent of the config files) has mention of the DS1307, but there's no mention of the DS3231 in it - i.e.:

```
CONFIG_RTC_DRV_DS1307=m  
CONFIG_RTC_DRV_DS1307_CENTURY=y
```

Any clues or diagnostics would be welcome.

Comment: Are you running Ubuntu or  Raspberry Pi OS?

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04 here, @David

Just spotted an amazing guide that seems to solve this:

https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=330201#p1977333

Comment: Seconded - I also had difficulty getting a DS3231 working with Ubuntu 22.04 on a Raspberry Pi 4B and the link mentioned by stonebreaker worked (https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=330201#p1977333)